Definite integral of $e^{-ax^2+bx+cx^{-1}-dx^{-2}}$
I need to find a close-form expression for the following definite integral:
$$
\int_{0}^{\infty}\exp\left(-ax^{2} + bx + cx^{-1} -dx^{-2}\,\right)\,{\rm d}x
$$
where $a,b,c,\ \mbox{and}\ d$ are all positive real numbers.

My approach was to use the summation definition for the exponenential function:
$\displaystyle{\rm e}^{x} = \sum_{t=0}^{\infty}
\frac{x^{t}}{t!}$
and expand $\large{\rm e}^{cx^{-1}}$ and $\large{\rm e}^{-dx^{-2}}$
as
\begin{align}
& \int_0^\infty e^{-ax^2+bx}\sum_{t=0}^{\infty} \frac{(cx^{-1})^t}{t!}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-dx^{-2})^k}{k!}dx
\\[2mm] & = \sum_{t=0}^{\infty} \frac{(c)^t}{t!}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-d)^k}{k!} \int_0^\infty x^{-t-2k} e^{-ax^2+bx}dx
\end{align}
Although, Mathematica has an answer for the final integral expression, it is restricted for $\left\vert t + 2k\right\vert < 1$ cases.
If possible, I prefer a solution that don't involves summations, or that has at most only one summation symbol.


Why do you think a closed form exists?

Maybe you can complex the square for $ax^2+bx$ or $c x^{-1}+d(x^{-1})^2$.
